# Vue JS Reload Button not working (v-on:click)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dom-events

After struggling hours to implement a simple AJAX Call, I am now struggling with a reload button. As far as I can see the syntax is `v-on:click="functionName"`.

In my case the Method I want to use is `fetchData` so -> `v-on:click="fetchData"`.

However it does Nothing.

This is my vue Code:

```
<script>
    var url = '{{ route('getAllFiles') }}';
    new Vue({
        el: '#fileTable',

        data: {
            files: [],
            filesAreReady: false
        },

        created: function(){
            this.fetchData();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData: function(){
                var self = this;
                self.filesAreReady = false;
                self.files = [];
                $.get(url, function(data){
                    self.files = $.parseJSON(data);
                    self.filesAreReady = true;
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is what PhpStorm tells me about `v-on`:
[image]

I'm using the latest version of Vue through the UNPKG.com CDN.

Comment: Does your 'fetchData' method work when the page loads?
Does the method get called? 
What's the status code returned?
Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes the fetchData works on pageload. No errors in the console.

Comment: @Scarwolf can you tell if the fetchData method is called when the button is clicked (set a breakpoint inside it)? Can you show is your template?

Comment: You can use `@click` as an alternative. Maybe you have some restrictions from another templating engine.

Comment: I'm using vue inside of Laravels Blade template engine if that would help.

Comment: Did my suggestion from above help?

Comment: Sadly not @CristiJora

Comment: @Scarwolf Did you solve it?

Comment: @ricopo Not yet sadly.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the method so `fetchData(){}` instead `fetchData: function () {}` and in the button calling the function `@click="fetchData()"`